# Is it possible to add a Route to a View in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am a bit new to all of this.

I know you can specify a route for an API Controller in MVC.

What I would like to do is specify a route to a View.

So, my View is called `ImageUploader` and is saved under the Folder called `Service`

This is my controller:

```
[Route("Sync")]
public ActionResult ImageUploader()
{
    return View();
}
```

When I type in the browser:

```
http://My _Domain/Sync
```

it returns

> resource not found.

So, I thought I would put

```
[Route("")]
public class ServiceController : Controller
```

on top of my class controller but this gave me the same error.

Can I do this easily with Route tags?

Here is the content of my `RouteConfig`:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");      
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();        
}
```

Comment: Do you have attribute based routing switched on in your application?

Comment: @LaurenceFrost Hi, I edited my question to show you what is in my RegisterRoutes. is this what you mean?

Comment: The mapping needs to go before custom routes

Comment: Take a look at the links I provided with my answer. It explains everything.

Comment: @Nkosi I got it to work. I did say I am knew to most of this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5)

**[Enabling Attribute Routing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/#enabling-attribute-routing)**

To enable attribute routing, call `MapMvcAttributeRoutes` during configuration.

```
public class RouteConfig {

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");              

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

[Route Prefixes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/#route-prefixes)

Use a tilde (~) on the method attribute to override the route prefix if needed:

```
public class ServiceController : Controller {
    //eg GET /Sync
    [Route("~/Sync")]
    public ActionResult ImageUploader() {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, I put that all in and I got this error (which I am googling now) A direct route cannot use the parameter 'controller'. Specify a literal path in place of this parameter to create a route to a controller.

Comment: thanks.  just tried it and it did not work I am afraid :(

Comment: I recreated the controller and view just like you explained in your post and was able to browse to `/Sync` using attribute routing.

Comment: hi, sorry for the delay. I shall recheck.  What version of mvc are you using? thanks

Comment: I am using **ASP.NET MVC 5**

Comment: Hi, i am afraid not. Out of interest do you have other mappings in the RegisterRoutes?

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me!